# Passing Props from Route to Component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react with react-router for a project and I need to pass props to the child component from the route.

I have this setup:

**App.js**

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/' render={()=><Home num="2" someProp={100}/>} />
  <Route path='/roster' component={Roster}/>
</Switch>
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome to the Tornadoes Website!</h1><p>{this.props.num}</p>
  </div>
)

export default Home
```

The problem is that the home component always gives the error 'undefined'. I am unable to understand how to resolve this. If I remove the props from Home.js, the component renders just fine. But when I try accessing the props, it gives error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stateless components don't access props through `this`. They're passed in as an argument to the function.

```
const Home = props => (
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome to the Tornadoes Website!</h1><p>{props.num}</p>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/' render={()=><Home num="2" someProp={100}/>} />
  <Route path='/roster' component={Roster}/>
</Switch>
```

Home

```
import React from 'react'

const Home = (props) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome to the Tornadoes Website!</h1><p>{props.someProp} {props.num} </p>
  </div>
)

export default Home
```

Since you named your prop someProp in App.js to acess it you need to do props.someProp, the name has to match the name you passed it down as. The same goes for the num props which holds the "2".

example
In parent component render Child
`<Child prop1={"hello"} fun={"this is a fun prop} />`

now in child

```
const Child = (props) => (
<div> 
 {props.prop1} will render hello {props.fun} will render this is a fun prop 
</div>
)
```